# How can I fix my function to correctly identify the odd number in the even number array?

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays, algorithm

I created a function, two actually, the first one checks if an array is an even number and the second one does two things: find the **odd** number in the **even** number array(if the array is even) and finds the **even** number in the **odd** number array(if the array is odd). But in the first case (i.e when i find the **odd** number in the **even** number array) and run it against a test case (i.e [0, 1, 2]), it outputs 0 instead of 1.

```js
function isMostlyEven(array, thresholdPercentage) {
    let evenCount = 0;
    let totalCount = 0;
  
    for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i] % 2 === 0) {
            evenCount++;
        }
        totalCount++;
    }
  
    const evenPercentage = (evenCount / totalCount) * 100;
  
    if (evenPercentage >= thresholdPercentage) {
        return true;
    }else {
        return false;
    }
}
  
function findOutlier(integers){
    if (isMostlyEven(integers, 80)) {
        for (let i = 0; i < integers.length; i++) {
            const int = Math.abs(integers[i]);
            if (int % 2 === 1) { // searches an arr of even nums for odd nums
                return int; // where the error is; that is returns 0 instead of 1(the odd num);
            }
        }   
    } else if (!isMostlyEven(integers, 80)) {
        for (let i = 0; i < integers.length; i++) {
            const int = Math.abs(integers[i]);
            if (int % 2 === 0) { // searches an arr of odd nums for even nums
                return int;
            }
        }
    }
}

const intArr = [0, 1, 2]; // should output 1 not 0
console.log(findOutlier(intArr));
```

Comment: Your array is not "mostly even", because less than 80% of the content is even.

Comment: Your array is **not** 80% even so `isMostlyEven` returns false

Comment: @Konrad thanks! I reduced it to 60% now it works fine

Answer (score 2):

The reason it outputs 0 instead of 1 is that the **evenPercentage** will always be below 80% until length of **intArr** is greater than 4. To be mostly even with 80 thresholdPercentage the array must contain at least 4 even numbers.